# Convert text file into Excel

Tags: excel, text-files, vba

I need to convert text file to Excel file. I found articles regarding this but my requirement is little different so I am not getting any idea.

I have text file including rows in this format

```
Jun 13 07:35:08 mail dovecot: pop3-login: Login: user=<veena,.patel@test.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=102.201.122.131, lip=103.123.113.83, mpid=33178, session=<Wfdfdfcxvc>
```

I want to create Excel file having four columns:-

- first column includes "Jun 13 07:35:08" of above row
- second column includes "pop3" of above row
- third column includes "veena,.patel@test.com"
- and fourth column includes "102.201.122.131"

All other data is not required in Excel. How can I do this? I know this is not what I wanted. I should have put some code about what I have tried first, but really I'm not getting any idea.

Comment: The first question is if you want to do this using Excel functions or if you wish to accomplish this using Excel VBA. If you are leaning towards the latter you might want to change the tags on your post and add [Excel-VBA], so you are getting the appropriate attention. Furthermore, you are right and this website is not a free code writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) with **their** code. So, just to get you started and give you ideas: http://www.homeandlearn.org/open_a_text_file_in_vba.html

Comment: actually i heard first time about excel VBA. i want  to generate excel file having 4 columns as i stated above.either by code or as u said by VBA..

using code i think i can read text file line by and can get chars between user=< and >  into one string and create excel having column of that.is that possible..or  VBA is better option. both option are new for me

Comment: I recommend that you (in a first step and to learn some VBA) record some things in Excel with the VBA macro recorder: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_HQGHPBYoo Afterwards, have a look at the code and try to understand it by highlighting VBA key-words and pressing `F1`. Also, I'd recommend reading the above link I've posted. Afterwards you should be set to provide a first solution to the above problem yourself. If you're still having problems, feel free to come back here and ask for specific advice on something you have attempted to code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName))
            {
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
                {
                    //string fileContant = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName);
                    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    List<Country> countries = new List<Country>();
                    Country country = null;
                    string line;
                    string[] arrLine;
                    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);
                    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                        {
                            if (line.Contains("rip="))
                            {
                                arrLine = line.Split(new string[] { "mail" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                                if (arrLine.Length > 1)
                                {
                                    sb.Append(arrLine[0] + ";");
                                    if (line.Contains("pop3-login:"))
                                    {
                                        sb.Append("pop3;");
                                    }
                                    else if (line.Contains("imap-login:"))
                                    {
                                        sb.Append("imap;");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        sb.Append(";");
                                    }
                                    arrLine = line.Split(new string[] { "user=<" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                                    if (arrLine.Length > 1)
                                    {
                                        arrLine = arrLine[1].Split(new string[] { ">," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                                        if (arrLine.Length > 1)
                                        {
                                            sb.Append(arrLine[0] + ";");
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            sb.Append(";");
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        sb.Append(";");
                                    }

                                    arrLine = line.Split(new string[] { "rip=" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                                    if (arrLine.Length > 1)
                                    {
                                        arrLine = arrLine[1].Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                                        if (arrLine.Length > 1)
                                        {
                                            sb.Append(arrLine[0] + ";");

                                            country = countries.FirstOrDefault(a => a.IP == arrLine[0]);
                                            if (country != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(country.IP))
                                            {
                                                sb.Append(country.Name + ";");
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                sb.Append(GetCountryByIP(arrLine[0],ref countries) + ";");
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            sb.Append(";;");
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        sb.Append(";;");
                                    }
                                    sb.Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    file.Close();

                    DialogResult dialogResult = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
                    string saveFileName=Application.StartupPath + @"\data.csv";
                    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        saveFileName = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
                    }

                    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(saveFileName, sb.ToString());
                    MessageBox.Show("File Save at " + saveFileName);
                    fileName = string.Empty;
                    textBox1.Text = string.Empty;

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("File Not Found");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Select File");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Message:" + ex.Message + " InnerException:" + ex.InnerException);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is java, what does it have to do with the tags excel, excel vba?

Answer (score 1):

If you are up to VBA -after you have watched some tutorials- you need this approach.

1. Get the text file by an [EOF method.](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/read-data-from-text-file.html)

2. A UDF for each of your desired criteria using [REGEX](http://analystcave.com/excel-regex-tutorial/) would be my approach -hint: you can check your regex logic [here](http://regexr.com/)-.

Here's an example for extracting the email:

```
Function UserInString(StringToAnalyze As String) As String
Dim regex As Object: Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
Dim Regexmatches As Variant
Dim ItemMatch As Variant
    With regex
      .Pattern = "[a-z]{1,99}[,][.][A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"
      .Global = True
    End With

    If regex.Test(StringToAnalyze) = True Then 'there's a user in the string! ' 1. If regex.Test(StringToAnalyze) = True
    Set Regexmatches = regex.Execute(StringToAnalyze)
    For Each ItemMatch In Regexmatches
      UserInString = IIf(UserInString = "", ItemMatch, ItemMatch & "," & UserInString)
    Next ItemMatch
    Else ' 1. If regex.Test(StringToAnalyze) = True
    UserInString = "There's no user in the string!"
    End If ' 1. If regex.Test(StringToAnalyze) = True
End Function
```

[image]

[image]